# Check if Windows user credentials have access to a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

The user enters data in the form. When the save button is pressed, I execute a SQL query to save the data.

I would like to know:

1. If the user has write access to the database so I can display an error if they don't
2. If the select/insert statement was successfully executed

My general code looks like this:

```
string query = "some query text for an insert, select, or update statement";
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   connection.Open();

   try
   {
      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
      {
          // I am paramterizing the query like this
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@<param>", <value>);

          SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
          dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
      }
   }
   catch (SqlException exception)
   {
       // Will I get an exception if the user does not have credentials to access this database?
       MessageBox.Show("An error occurred trying to save data to SQL: " + exception.Message);
   }

   connection.Close();
   // How do I know if the select/insert was successful?
}
```

At this point, I look in the `DataTable` to find the data to display in a `DataGridView` to the user (for select queries).

Comment: Just run the query. SQL Server will tell you if they don't have permission, and it will come back as an exception which you can catch in C#. No need to check separately really

Comment: Don't use `Parameters.AddWithValue`, use `Parameters.Add`. In this scenario, if your column isn't an `nvarchar`, then your query won't be SARGable, as your parameter will be passed as an `nvarchar` (causing the column to be implicitly converted from a `varchar` to an `nvarchar`). See [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and A[ddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: T-SQL permissions are a minefield of vague things with various hierarchies that influence ultimate access; checking if a user can do something rather than trying it and handling the error is generally not worth it (aside from the inherent race condition you always get if permissions change after you check). `SqlException` has an `Errors` property you can inspect for specific conditions by `.Number` (if you want to present a more user-friendly message for particular cases).

Comment: `How do I know if the select/insert was successful?`...because there won't be any exceptions.

Comment: BTW `INSERT` commands don't have a `WHERE` clause. It also doesn't have a `SET` clause. That's invalid SQL. Not sure what you're trying to achieve with that query, it doesn't make sense. Maybe you've got mixed up between `INSERT` and `UPDATE`? They have different purposes and different syntax. If you're still confused, go and take a basic SQL tutorial.

Comment: And also even in a valid query, `where @someCondition` won't work - you can't parameterise an entire expression like that. You can parameterise a _value_ though - e.g. `where fieldX = @someOtherValue` would be valid.

Comment: You can check the result from `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` to tell you how many rows were inserted or updated. Not sure why you want to use an adapter for this. And you should not be caching your connection object, create it on the spot from the connectionstring, and dispose with `using`

Comment: @ADyson You're totally right, I originally had a select statement and then changed to insert without thinking about the rest of it. And of course I need to say `where someColName = @somevalue`. I'll update the question text to make some sense.

Comment: @Charlieface I don't know how to get the data back from a select statement if I use `ExecuteNonQuery`, this is why I am using the `SqlDataAdapter`. If it's not the best way, I'm very open to suggestions. Most of what I have is from reading other Stack Exchange posts and trying out the code.

Comment: `insert` doesn't return any data? Yeah you could use an adapter for a `select` but often using a reader from `ExecuteReader` is better, especially if you want to load straight into objects. Just make sure you dispose everything with `using`